# can't get this responsive menu to work x(

Tags: css, menu, dropdown, responsive

Works fine on mobile but at fullscreen I can't select the dropdown options on hover because the option vanishes.

My code:

```js
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav { 
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 float: left;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #254441;
 }

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 20px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:17px;
 text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
 top: 60px; 
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px;
 /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
 left:170px; 
}

 
/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

 #logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
 }

 nav {
  margin: 0;
 }

 /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
 /* Also hide the  */
 .toggle + a,
 .menu {
  display: none;
 }

 /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
 .toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #254441;
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
 }

 .toggle:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
 }

 /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
 [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  }

 nav ul ul .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }

 nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
 }

 nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #000000;
 }
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a{
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px; 
 }
  
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #212121; 
 }

 /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
 nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position:static;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
 }
  
 /* Hide menus on hover */
 nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
 }
  
 /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
 nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }

 nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
  /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

 }

}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

 nav ul li {
  display:block;
  width: 94%;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">WordPress +</label>
                    <a href="#">WordPress</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Themes and stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul> 

                </li>
                <li>

                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
                <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li>
                       
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

here is a fiddle so you can see what I'm talking about guys:

http://jsfiddle.net/p1mrtuex/9/

help please!

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu is further away from the navigation. Change the `nav ul ul` to 40px. it moves the dropdown closer to the nav and now you can choose the dropdown.

```js
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
        });
```

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .toggle,
    [id^=drop] {
     display: none;
    }

    /* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
    nav { 
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #254441;
    }

    #logo {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 30px;
     float: left;
     font-size:20px;
     line-height: 60px;
    }

    /* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
     * we need to add a clear after the container. */

    nav:after {
     content:"";
     display:table;
     clear:both;
    }

    /* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
     * and adding "position:reltive" */
    nav ul {
     float: right;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
     }
     
    /* Positioning the navigation items inline */
    nav ul li {
     margin: 0px;
     display:inline-block;
     float: left;
     background-color: #254441;
     }

    /* Styling the links */
    nav a {
     display:block;
     padding:14px 20px; 
     color:#FFF;
     font-size:17px;
     text-decoration:none;
    }


    nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

    /* Background color change on Hover */
    nav a:hover { 
     background-color: #000000; 
    }

    /* Hide Dropdowns by Default
     * and giving it a position of absolute */
    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        top: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
     
    /* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
    }
     
    /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
    nav ul ul li {
     width:170px;
     float:none;
     display:list-item;
     position: relative;
    }

    /* Second, Third and more Tiers 
     * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
     * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
    */
    nav ul ul ul li {
     position: relative;
     top:-60px;
     /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
     left:170px; 
    }

     
    /* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
    li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
    li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


    /* Media Queries
    --------------------------------------------- */

    @media all and (max-width : 768px) {

     #logo {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      float: none;
     }

     nav {
      margin: 0;
     }

     /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
     /* Also hide the  */
     .toggle + a,
     .menu {
      display: none;
     }

     /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
     .toggle {
      display: block;
      background-color: #254441;
      padding:14px 20px; 
      color:#FFF;
      font-size:17px;
      text-decoration:none;
      border:none;
     }

     .toggle:hover {
      background-color: #000000;
     }

     /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
     [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
      display: block;
     }

     /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
     nav ul li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      }

     nav ul ul .toggle,
     nav ul ul a {
      padding: 0 40px;
     }

     nav ul ul ul a {
      padding: 0 80px;
     }

     nav a:hover,
      nav ul ul ul a {
      background-color: #000000;
     }
      
     nav ul li ul li .toggle,
     nav ul ul a,
      nav ul ul ul a{
      padding:14px 20px; 
      color:#FFF;
      font-size:17px; 
     }
      
      
     nav ul li ul li .toggle,
     nav ul ul a {
      background-color: #212121; 
     }

     /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
     nav ul ul {
      float: none;
      position:static;
      color: #ffffff;
      /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
     }
      
     /* Hide menus on hover */
     nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
     nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display: none;
     }
      
     /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
     nav ul ul li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
     }

     nav ul ul ul li {
      position: static;
      /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

     }
      
      
      /*to overwrite desktop default behaviour*/
      nav ul li > ul, nav ul li:hover > ul {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
      }
      


    }

    @media all and (max-width : 330px) {

     nav ul li {
      display:block;
      width: 94%;
     }

    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

            <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">WordPress +</label>
                        <a href="#">WordPress</a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Themes and stuff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                        </ul> 

                    </li>
                    <li>

                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
                    <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                        <li>
                           
                        <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                        <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Cheers

Comment: I changed this but still can't select the lower dropdown options, don't know what could possibly be causing this.

Comment: Tried a lower number than 40px? Try zero to start with

Comment: Tried top:0px and top:100% and still nothing. there is something wonky here, it's like the dropdowns don't wanna be selected

Comment: I added the full code for you in my post. If you are running it, do a full screen and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your drop down is position way below the hover state of your navigation. Instead of

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
```

try change to:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    top: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

To style for mobile navigation, overwrite the default desktop behavior

```
@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

**Example:**

```js
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav { 
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 float: left;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #254441;
 }

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 20px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:17px;
 text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    top: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px;
 /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
 left:170px; 
}

 
/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

 #logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
 }

 nav {
  margin: 0;
 }

 /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
 /* Also hide the  */
 .toggle + a,
 .menu {
  display: none;
 }

 /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
 .toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #254441;
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
 }

 .toggle:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
 }

 /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
 [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  }

 nav ul ul .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }

 nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
 }

 nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #000000;
 }
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a{
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px; 
 }
  
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #212121; 
 }

 /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
 nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position:static;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
 }
  
 /* Hide menus on hover */
 nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
 }
  
 /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
 nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }

 nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
  /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

 }
  
  
  /*to overwrite desktop default behaviour*/
  nav ul li > ul, nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  


}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

 nav ul li {
  display:block;
  width: 94%;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">WordPress +</label>
                    <a href="#">WordPress</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Themes and stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul> 

                </li>
                <li>

                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
                <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li>
                       
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: the padding undoes the changes of the top I think, tried it but still won't let me select the lower dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0):

You have this rule in there:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    top: 60px; 
}
```

If you change `top: 60px;` to `top: 40px;`, it will move up close enought to become selectable.

Here is a fiddle where it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hm41j6u1/1/